# Is the change in camera handling, related to the characters state of mind?

Tags: cinematography, carnage

In the movie Carnage 2011 by Roman Polanski, we see a gradual change in the camera handling style. When the film starts almost all the scenes are shot with fixed point camera view. But as gradually Penelope, Nancy, Alan and Michael start getting drunk (They had scotch neat) the shots gradually change to hand held camera views. My question being :

1. Is this camera view related to the fact that the characters were starting to get drunk and losing their balance?
2. Is this typical of Roman Polanksi's style of taking shots? Because in other films like The Pianist or The Ghostwriter, I haven't noticed such a thing.

Please find these scenes on and after 1:03:36 here.

As screen shots wouldn't be much of a help I refrained from adding them here.

Comment: Please help me add new tags here as I could not.